# Actionscript URLRequest cache problem

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, caching, actionscript

I have a caching problem in my action script, and to get over it i added the timestamp as recommended:

```
var urlRequest:URLRequest = new  URLRequest("http://mydomain.com?time=" + new Date().getTime());
var urlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();                  
urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, function(evt:Event) {    
...
});
urlLoader.load(urlRequest);
```

but am getting the following error:

```
Error #2044: Unhandled ioError:. text=Error #2032: Stream Error. URL: http://mydomain.com ?time=1314645911941
    at Main/Operate()
    at Main()
```

If i paste it in the url in the browser it loads fine, i guess the problem is coming from the A.S,

any idea y?
Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to communicate with a php file? if so you need to specify it in the url request like so http://mydomain.com/phpfile.php?time=1314645911941, yours is currently like this http://mydomain.com_____?time=1314645911941

Comment: tx, but the url that i am acceding to to is not a certain file, it is an mvc app (not in my controll)

Comment: Are the code and error blocks that you've posted copied directly from your code and error output? I see that there's a space in the error message after .com, while your code doesn't have that space. That difference seems peculiar.

Comment: @Sexy-M-F going to need more information on what exactly your trying to request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an un-handled event ioError

```
urlLoader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, function(evt:Event){trace(evt.toString)} );
```

Chances are your application is having an issue with loading it and can't report it to you due to no event listeners for that event.
There are a few events when loading any outside data,image,SWf, or anything really that you need to handle just to be sure and will help with debugging.

Here is a list I try to always imnplement

```
urlLoader.addEventListener(ErrorEvent.ERROR, errorHandlerErrorEvent);
urlLoader.addEventListener(AsyncErrorEvent.ASYNC_ERROR, errorHandlerAsyncErrorEvent);
urlLoader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, errorHandlerIOErrorEvent);
urlLoader.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, errorHandlerSecurityErrorEvent);


urlLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.INIT, initHandler);
urlLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, infoIOErrorEvent);
urlLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoadComplete);
urlLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_STATUS, httpStatusHandler )
```

Oh yeah and please please use named functions not nameless ones.
This is an OOP language and nameless functions are not good OOP at all.